# Как удаленно узнать почему Android приложение крашится?

Tags: android

Есть приложение на Android. Тестировал на 4+ и 5+ версиях.
Пользователь установил на 4.4.2 и приложение сразу после запуска крашится.
Лично взять это устройство не могу, нужно как-то удаленно узнать причину или собрать логи и отправить их себе. Могу дистанционно сказать пользователю, что нужно для этого сделать.
Про разные сервисы сбора логов знаю.
Поставил в приложение Rollbar и инициализировал его в стартовой активности в onCreate, но ошибка не захватывается, видимо она выскакивает раньше этого момента.
Какие есть способы узнать причину ошибки?

Answer (score 4):

Я для таких целей использую [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/) с отправкой логов на email.
`build.gradle`

```
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
```

Класс `Application`:

```
@ReportsCrashes(mailTo = "reports@yourdomain.com",
                mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
                resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
public class MyApplication extends Application {
        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base);

            // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
            ACRA.init(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

У нас для этого и некоторых других вещей (на прим. сбор статистики) используется
[Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/?locale=ru) от Twitter